Arduino TFT Touch Screen Interface Only Returns One Button Option
I'm trying to create an arduino code that returns a value for the button that was pressed as the user choice. However, whichever button I press the only return is 2. Also, whenever pressing other buttons, button 2 is the one that seems to have been pressed.
What could it be? Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
This is the current code I have.
#include <MCUFRIEND_kbv.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>

#define MINPRESSURE 500
#define MAXPRESSURE 2000
#define PRETO   0x0000
#define VERMELHO     0xF800
#define VERDE   0x07E0
#define BRANCO   0xFFFF

#define XP 6
#define XM A2
#define YP A1
#define YM 7

#define TS_LEFT 945
#define TS_RT 221
#define TS_TOP 916
#define TS_BOT 201

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);
Adafruit_GFX_Button botoes[4];
MCUFRIEND_kbv tft;

int posX, posY;
int escolha = 0;

bool obterToque(void) {
    TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
    pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);      
    pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(YP, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(XM, HIGH);
    bool pressed = (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE);
    if (pressed) {
        posX = map(p.x, TS_LEFT, TS_RT, 0, 320); 
        posY = map(p.y, TS_TOP, TS_BOT, 0, 240);
        // Debugging: Print the raw and mapped touch coordinates
        //Serial.print("Raw X: "); Serial.print(p.x); Serial.print(", Raw Y: "); Serial.println(p.y);
        //Serial.print("Mapped X: "); Serial.print(posX); Serial.print(", Mapped Y: "); Serial.println(posY);
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  uint16_t ID = tft.readID();
  tft.begin(ID);
  tft.setRotation(3);
  telaInicial();
}

void telaInicial(){
  tft.fillScreen(PRETO);
  botoes[0].initButton(&tft,  160, 40, 250, 40, BRANCO, VERDE, PRETO, "1. Normal Sinus", 2);
  botoes[1].initButton(&tft, 160, 95, 250, 40, BRANCO, VERDE, PRETO, "2. Atrial Fibrillation", 2);
  botoes[2].initButton(&tft, 160, 150, 250, 40, BRANCO, VERDE, PRETO, "3. Ventricular Ectopy", 2);
  botoes[3].initButton(&tft, 160, 205, 250, 40, BRANCO, VERDE, PRETO, "4. SV Arrhythmia", 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    botoes[i].drawButton(false);
  }
}

void TeclaPressionada(bool teclaTocada) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    botoes[i].press(teclaTocada && botoes[i].contains(posX, posY));
  }
  checkPressedButton();
}

void checkPressedButton() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (botoes[i].justPressed()) {
      checkPressed(i);
    }
  }
}

void esperaSoltar() {
  while (obterToque()) {
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
}

void checkPressed(int button) {
    botoes[button].drawButton(true);
    esperaSoltar();
    botoes[button].drawButton();

    if (button == 0) {
        escolha = 1;
    } else if (button == 1) {
        escolha = 2;
    } else if (button == 2) {
        escolha = 3;
    } else if (button == 3) {
        escolha = 4;
    }

    Serial.print("Escolha: ");
    Serial.println(escolha);
}

void loop() {
  bool toque = obterToque();
  TeclaPressionada(toque);
}

Thanks for reading.

why is the debugging code disabled?

Hi everyone, eventually I found a tutorial that solves this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn-1hHjRyjo

I managed to find an answer on this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn-1hHjRyjo
Here's the screen project I'm working on.
#include <MCUFRIEND_kbv.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>

MCUFRIEND_kbv tft;

#define XP 6
#define XM A2
#define YP A1
#define YM 7

#define TS_LEFT 945
#define TS_RT 221
#define TS_TOP 916
#define TS_BOT 201

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);

// Definição de cores
#define BLACK 0x0000
#define BLUE 0x2015
#define BLUE2 0x0DDE
#define RED 0xF800
#define GREEN 0x07E0
#define CYAN 0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW 0xFFE0
#define WHITE 0xFFFF
#define GREY 0xC639

// Variáveis Globais
uint32_t startRead = 0;
int page = 0;
int posX;
int posY;

// Variables for ECG data
float ecgValue = 0.0; // Current ECG value received from serial
int scale = 75;      // Scale factor for voltage values
int startY;          // Vertical center for the waveform
int ecgIndex = 0;    // Current index for plotting
int xPos = 0;        // Horizontal position to draw the next data point
int choice = 0;       // User rhythm selection variable to lead to desired rhythm


#define MINPRESSURE 10
#define MAXPRESSURE 1000

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("TFT Test");
  tft.reset();
  delay(500);
  uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();
  tft.begin(identifier);
  tft.setRotation(1);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);

  tft.println("Programa feito por: ");
  tft.println("Giovanne Lucas");
  tft.println("Barreto");
  tft.println("giovanne.pinto@medicina.uniceplac.edu.br");

  delay(2000);
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  displayBootScreen();
  delay(5000);

  telainicial();
  page = 0;

  startY = tft.height() / 2; // Calculate vertical center for ECG plotting
}

void displayBootScreen() {
    int screenWidth = tft.width();
    int screenHeight = tft.height();
    tft.drawBitmap(0, 0, bootImage, screenWidth, screenHeight, WHITE);
    delay(5000);
    tft.fillScreen(0x0000); // Placeholder: Fill screen with black
    tft.setTextColor(0xFFFF);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    //tft.setCursor(10, screenHeight / 2 - 10);
    //tft.print("Booting...");
}

void telainicial() {
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 310, 30, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(7, 7, 306, 26, 0, BLUE);
  tft.setCursor(120, 10);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.print("MENU");

  tft.fillRoundRect(50, 55, 220, 40, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(52, 57, 216, 36, 0, GREY);
  tft.setCursor(60, 65);
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("1. Ritmo Sinusal");

  tft.fillRoundRect(50, 115, 220, 40, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(52, 117, 216, 36, 0, GREY);
  tft.setCursor(60, 124);
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("2. Fibrilacao Atrial");

  tft.fillRoundRect(50, 175, 220, 40, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(52, 177, 216, 36, 0, GREY);
  tft.setCursor(60, 185);
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("3. Ectopia Ventricular");
}

void tela1() {
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 310, 30, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(7, 7, 306, 26, 0, BLUE);
  tft.setCursor(120, 10);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Ritmo Sinusal");

  tft.fillTriangle(30, 20, 50, 30, 50, 10, GREY); // Botão de voltar
}

void tela2() {
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 310, 30, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(7, 7, 306, 26, 0, BLUE);
  tft.setCursor(90, 10);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Fibrilacao Atrial");

  tft.fillTriangle(30, 20, 50, 30, 50, 10, GREY); // Botão de voltar
}

void tela3() {
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 310, 30, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(7, 7, 306, 26, 0, BLUE);
  tft.setCursor(90, 10);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Ectopia Ventricular");

  tft.fillTriangle(30, 20, 50, 30, 50, 10, GREY); // Botão de voltar
}

void tela4() {
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 310, 30, 0, BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(7, 7, 306, 26, 0, BLUE);
  tft.setCursor(90, 10);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.print("Arritmia Supraventricular");

  tft.fillTriangle(30, 20, 50, 30, 50, 10, GREY); // Botão de voltar
}


void plotECG() {
  static int xPos = 0; // horizontal position to draw the next data point
  static int startY = tft.height() / 2; // vertical center for the waveform
  static int lastY = startY; // previous Y coordinate

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    float ecgValue = Serial.parseFloat();
    int y1 = startY - (int)(ecgValue * scale); // calculate Y coordinate based on ECG value

    // draw a line from the previous point to the current point
    tft.drawLine(xPos - 1, lastY, xPos, y1, RED);

    // update lastY and xPos for the next loop iteration
    lastY = y1;
    xPos = (xPos + 1) % tft.width(); // wrap xPos around the screen width

    // clear the screen and redraw the grid if necessary
    if (xPos == 0) {
      tft.fillScreen(WHITE); // clear the screen
      drawECGGrid(); // redraw the grid
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(XM, LOW);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(YP, HIGH);
  pinMode(YM, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(YM, LOW);
  pinMode(XP, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(XP, HIGH);

  if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE) {
    posX = map(p.y, TS_LEFT, TS_RT, 0, 320);
    posY = map(p.x, TS_TOP, TS_BOT, 0, 240);

    if (page == 0) {
      if (posX > 52 && posX < 268 && posY > 57 && posY < 93)  //RITMO SINUSAL
      {
        page = 1;
        choice = 1;
        tela1();
        delay(50); // debounce
      }
      if (posX > 52 && posX < 268 && posY > 117 && posY < 153)  //FIBRILACAO ATRIAL
      {
        page = 2;
        choice = 2;
        tela2();
        delay(50); // debounce
      }
      if (posX > 52 && posX < 268 && posY > 177 && posY < 213)  //ECTOPIA VENTRICULAR
      {
        page = 3;
        choice = 3;
        tela3();
        delay(50); // debounce
      }
    } else {
      // Verifica o botão de voltar
      if (posX > 30 && posX < 50 && posY > 10 && posY < 30)  //botão voltar
      {
        telainicial();
        page = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (page == 1) {
    plotECG(); // Ritmo Sinusal
  } else if (page == 2) {
    plotECG(); // Fibrilação Atrial
  } else if (page == 3) {
    plotECG(); // Ectopia Ventricular
  } else if (page == 4) {
    plotECG(); // Arritmia Supraventricular
  }

  // Always send the choice value to the serial port
  Serial.print("Choice: ");
  Serial.println(choice);

}

// Function to draw the ECG grid
void drawECGGrid() {
    int smallSquareSize = 10; // 10 pixels for small squares
    int largeSquareSize = 50; // 50 pixels for large squares

    uint16_t smallGridColor = GREY; // Light grey color for small squares
    uint16_t largeGridColor = 0x7BEF; // Darker grey color for large squares

    // Draw the small squares
    for (int x = 0; x <= tft.width(); x += smallSquareSize) {
        tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, tft.height(), smallGridColor);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= tft.height(); y += smallSquareSize) {
        tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, tft.width(), smallGridColor);
    }

    // Draw the large squares
    for (int x = 0; x <= tft.width(); x += largeSquareSize) {
        tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, tft.height(), largeGridColor);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= tft.height(); y += largeSquareSize) {
        tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, tft.width(), largeGridColor);
    }
}


what is the answer? ... what caused the problem?

I see that those are two different approaches for the same question. I think the second code example is better as it creates pages and refreshes the screen based on what the user touches. Instead of having multiple functions to handle the page selection.
